# Where to find declared variables and their values in the AngularJS application's object in the developer's console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand AngularJS at framework level. And I'm trying understand how it has been build under the hood since it is after all a JavaScript framework.

So, after creation of a small angular application, when I enter **this** in the developer console, I get a reference to angular JS application and it's object.
And I'm pretty much sure, If I go through it, I get to find some interesting facts and knowledge on how exactly the entire framework work internally. And I'm on it.

Here's the small application what I've built
    [image]

And here's the console
[image]

So, as you can see in the console, I'm seeding the name of the application as a variable in the object of angular js application.
Similarly I wanted to know, where to find declared controllers, and scoped variables in the same object.

Comment: Pictures of code make it hard to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It is easier to probe ones app if one uses `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

try this chrome extension for angular inspections
https://augury.rangle.io/

Comment: Does it support for angular js 1.x? Because I'm not getting anything in it